# Adding dynamic textbox values in database column by column

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have two tables forming foriegn key constraint tablename and Column_table. In table tablename I am going to store only table name entered by user and in another table column_table I am storing its column names.  column_table is having feilds as h1 to h40. The values of col_heading table will be inserted by the user using dymanic textbox which will be saved in column h1- h40 where tablename's id is matched in column_table. how to do it?

```
 following code is to display data and add dynamic textboxes.
 $select = "SELECT * FROM column_table";
 $result= mysqli_query($bd, $select);

 <table align="center" class="table " cellpadding="10"  id="user_table">
 <tr>
 <th>NAME</th>

</tr>
<?php

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{
 ?>
<tr id="row<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
 <td id="name_val<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
<td>
  <input type='button' class="edit_button btn-success btn" id="edit_button<?
 php echo $row['id'];?>" value="edit" onclick="edit_row('<?php echo $row['id'];?>');">
   <input type='button' class="save_button btn-success btn" id="save_button<?php echo $row['id'];?>" value="save" onclick="save_row('<?php echo $row['id'];?>');">
   <input type='button' class="delete_button btn-success btn" id="delete_button<?php echo $row['id'];?>" value="delete" onclick="delete_row('<?php echo $row['id'];?>');">
 </td>
 </tr>
 <?php
 }

?>

<tr id="new_row">
<td><input type="text" class="form-control1" id="new_name"></td>
 <td><input type="button" class="btn-success btn" value="Insert Row" 
  onclick="insert_row();" required></td>
  </tr>
   </table>
```

how to write its insert query?